# Order mysql table by non column elements

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an android app where users can view data according to the area they want. I am getting the area in my php back-end code. I have a table 'help' which has a column `name`. What I want to do is sort the entire table according to the percentage match using `similar_text` or something similar between users input and table `name` data in descending order.I don't know how to do it.This is how far I got.

```
<?php
require_once "Database/DB_Connect.php";
$db = new DB_Connect();
$db_conn = $db->connect();
$area=$_REQUEST['area']
$name1=array();
$query="SELECT `name` from `help`";
$result=mysqli_query($db_conn,$query);
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name=$row['name'];
    similar_text($area,$name,$percentage);
    $query1="SELECT * FROM `help` ORDER BY '$percentage' DESC ";
    $result1=mysqli_query($db_conn,$query1);
    while($row1=$result1->fetch_assoc()){
        $name1[]=$row1;
    }
}   
echo json_encode($name1);
$db_conn->close();
?>
```

The output I am getting is the entire table data multiple times order by `names` in descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the optimum answer or not, however, I came up with a solution.

```
<?php
require_once "Database/DB_Connect.php";
$db = new DB_Connect();
$db_conn = $db->connect();
$name1=array();
$id=array();
$area = $_REQUEST['area'];
$query="SELECT * FROM `help`";
$result=mysqli_query($db_conn,$query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name1[]=$row['name'];
    $id[]=$row['id'];
} 
$sorted_arr=array();
$sorted_id=array();
for($i=0; $i<count($name1); $i++) {
   $temp_arr[$i] = similar_text($search, $name1[$i]);
}
arsort($temp_arr);
foreach($temp_arr as $k => $v) {
    $sorted_arr[] = $name1[$k];
    $sorted_id[]=$id[$k];
}
$data = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($name1); $i++) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `help` WHERE `id`='$sorted_id[$i]' ";
    $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
    $data[]=$result->fetch_assoc();   
}
echo json_encode($data);
$db_conn->close();
?>
```